# Why do browsers automatically redirect to urls in location?

Tags: redirect, browser

When a response to a certain request is redirection, with status code 3XX and location header, it seems that the browser automatically redirects to the other page (by URLs included in location header).

But when I send the same request via cURL or postman, the response comes with the 3XX but no redirect occurs.

So I concluded that the redirection from the first case is not a basic response but an additional function that browsers.

If so where I can find the settings about this? If not, what is the main cause of this redirection?

Comment: Probably because browsers are designed in such a way that in case of such response status code, it will automatically redirect. cURL and Postman may not have such a feature.

Comment: The purpose of a redirect _is_ a redirect. Some clients may not automatically do this, but frankly it's a strange default. I can see an argument made that given curl is a developer tool it's useful to see the 3xx intermediate response, but not following redirects should be unusual. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser is trying to give the user a good experience.  If the web site returns a redirect, then the best user experience is for it to go ahead and do the redirect.  `cURL` and `wget` will also follow the redirects if you enable the option, but since those tools are mostly for diagnostics, the default is to have one request, one response.  It's up to the consumer to decide what to do with that response.

I'm not sure what you mean by "basic response".  The RFC does not require a redirect.  The request receives a response, and it's up to the recipient to decide what to do next.

Comment: Thanks for such a perfect answer Tim!
Understood how the things are going!